# Dynamic value on load in select tag in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angularjs for my application.I am trying to autofill select box with dynamic value.

Here is my select code.

```
    <select class="form-control" name="courseName" data-ng-
    model="exam.courseName" required="">
    <option data-ng-value="{{courseforstudent.courseName}}">
    {{courseforstudent.courseName}}
    </option> 
    </select>
```

If i remove data-ng-model then i am getting value what i wanted in select box on load.But after giving ng-model it disappears and it displays in dropdown.Again i need to select and then save.But i want it onload.I am binding it with exam object and i am sending it backened for saving.I am trying to display courseName automatically on load.Can anyone tell how to bind courseName value with ng-model?.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of the following ways

```
<select ng-model="exam.courseName" ng-options="c.courseName as c.courseName for c in courseforstudent"></select>
```

or

```
   <option ng-repeat="option in courseforstudent" value="{{option.courseName}}">{{option.courseName}}</option>
```

you can check this jsFiddle 
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/bjs3g/)